# How to linearize boolean expressionfor linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am trying to put a boolean expression into a linear program:

```
¬A ∧ B => C
```

but I am not sure how to do so.
I was thinking about the following equation:

```
0 <= (1-A) + B - 2* C <= 1
```

But somehow my program is telling me that I am having an infeasible solution with that.
Maybe someone can help

Answer (score 0):

```
0 <= (1-A) + B - 2* C <= 1
```

is surely not correct. E.g. it does not allow `a=b=0,c=1`. You are cutting off valid solutions.

Better is

```
 c >= b-a
```

Check:

```
a  b  b-a    c 
----------------
0  0   0    0,1
0  1   1     1
1  0  -1    0,1
1  1   0    0,1
```

Looks correct to me.